What main benefits does the Hex spell's ability check disadvantage provide?
A secondary effect of the spell Hex is to give disadvantage on ability checks.

...choose one ability when you cast the spell. The target has Disadvantage on ability checks made with the chosen ability.

In the 2014 rules, this used to be a valuable tool for increasing the success of certain ability contests, e.g. Shoving creatures into hazards and blocking pinch points, however the mechanics for grapple and shove have changed to saving throws:

Grapple. The target must succeed on a Strength or Dexterity saving throw...


Shove. The target must succeed on a Strength or Dexterity saving throw...

There are probably a few more relevant examples affected by this change, but it seems to drastically nerf the secondary effects of Hex. Detect Thoughts uses an ability check:

...the target can take an action on its turn to make an Intelligence (Arcana) check against your spell save DC, ending the spell on a success.

But, leveraging the combination is very situational. Can anyone think of regular uses for this, or has it become mostly vestigial?

There are still a few use-cases
..though they may be niche depending on the table.
After compiling the list, the in-combat uses have narrowed, with many of the ones I found in the Free Rules relying on synergy with other concentration spells--meaning you'd need an ally who uses them for the use-case to be viable. You'll see a higher ratio of utility, ambush, or even chase sequence use-cases. Roleplay reasons and uses for hex haven't changed, as @SeriousBri notes.
I would expect use-cases around Hiding to become the next most common in-combat uses of hex's Disadvantage feature. Others might find use with concentration spell synergy depending on the party.
Wisdom
You might still hex Wisdom to make it harder to:

Spot a Hiding creature (the Hide action is a contested roll of Stealth (DEX) vs. Perception (WIS))
Spot a pre-cast magical hazard, such as glyph of warding, spike growth, or symbol
Succeed in an Influence action on beasts (Animal Handling)
Succeed in a Search action
Apply an Inquisitive Rogue's Insightful Fighting[2] for sneak attack (contested Deception (CHA) vs. Insight (WIS))

You might also try to counter hunter's mark's Advantage on Perception and Survival checks to find the marked creature.
Intelligence
You might still hex Intelligence to make it harder to:

Discern non-damaging illusions like hallucinatory terrain, disguise self or major image (among others)
Throw off the deeper probing of the detect thoughts spell
Escape a maze spell

Charisma
You might still hex Charisma to make it harder to:

Succeed in an Influence action against people
Deceive an Inquisitive Rogue's Insightful Fighting[2] feature (contested Deception (CHA) vs. Insight (WIS))

Strength
You might still hex Strength to make it harder to:

Break out of a restraining effect after you have failed the initial saving throw, like with entangle, web, earthquake, or ensnaring strike. This also applies to a regular grapple.
Swim away from the Whirlpool variant of control water if you're in the area of effect
Break out of being chained or tied up, manacled, or restrained in a net
Follow a route requiring large jumps, climbing (if no climb speed) or swimming (if no swim speed)

You can also try to counter enlarge's Advantage on Strength checks if that is playing a role in a specific situation.
Dexterity
You might still hex Dexterity to make it harder to:

Succeed in a Hide action
Break out of being chained or tied up, or manacled
Get a high initiative roll[1]

Variable
A few effects may vary depending on the situation.

Dispel magic still requires a spellcasting ability check to dispel ongoing magical effects, which a properly chosen hex would impact. This would require knowing the right ability to hex.
A mounted combatant has Advantage on all checks to remain in the saddle so long as there is a saddle on the mount. If you're trying to get a foe out of the saddle (without or before killing the mount), a hex might help. Again, you'll need to figure out which ability to hex.

.
Your tactics, and your table's combat intricacies, may vary. Is it common for a combatant to Influence bystanders into joining against you in a fight? No, but I've played at tables where similar things have happened, and giving Disadvantage to a check like that would impact the tides of that fight.
Considering hex is most frequently used at the tables I frequent for the damage feature with little thought paid to the ability score part, I expect this forgetfulness will simply become more common.

 [1]: not every table considers an Initiative roll a standard ability check (mine doesn't), instead categorizing it as its own separate thing that only benefits from abilities and features that specifically interact with Initiative by name. Check with your DM to see how they prefer to handle it.
 [2]: Legacy 2014 5e content, Xanathar's Guide to Everything, p.45 .

In my 2014 games, this is often used against enemy casters to hamper their ability to Counterspell or Dispel Magic on the party casters.  When used against Dex, it not only hinders attempts to Hide, but if they do slip away, will disadvantage their Initiative if they are re-encountered within the relatively long duration.  I don't know whether these uses persist in 2024.

@Kirt: Counterspell is now a Con save by the target. Dispel Magic remains a spellcasting ability check, and Initiative remains a Dex check, so that still applies.

To add to your "restraining effects" point on Strength, it is applicable to the more accessible Grapple as well (which is Saving Throw for the initial one and checks for the escape)

This is an amazing list! I think you're right about most options being pretty niche, though.

Another for the list, an Inquisitive Rogue might make use of disadvantaged deception checks.

D&D Beyond includes XGtE content as "Expanded Rules", which is distinct from items marked as "Legacy".

@nonymous I don't use DDB, so I'll take your word for it. That being said, since some expanded content got updated and rereleased with the 2024 PHB, I find it useful to note that the Inquisitive isn't one of those that has specifically had a pass for the updated core rules. We're still in the phase of figuring out the limits of the backwards compatibility with all of the expanded content--while I'm sure this one's not too off, some folks will want to check it first to make sure it still works.

The out of combat uses have not changed
In combat you are right that the most common use is gone, but I used the spell for more, such as:

Strength - Arm wrestling contests at a fayre
Dexterity - Cause an acrobat to fail at a circus and give you a good laugh
Constitution - No idea
Intelligence - No idea
Wisdom - Lower perception when sneaking, lower insight when lying
Charisma - Hex a rival in a dance off, prank a friend trying to negotiate a discount

This relies on the whole "spells can't be detected unless they have a visible effect" rule which many DM's don't use (especially for hex which is often described as shadowy) but I have taken the spell purely for this kind of use several times.
